# Python - data extraction from MIDI files

Tags: python, midi, recurrent-neural-network, extract

Looking to read in massive amount of MIDI files and extract their data into groups - tick(time), pitch(note) and velocity(volume). The extracted data will be applied to a Recurrent Neural Network for further music generation.

I have been searching for libraries and located [python-midi](https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi). Here's my code:

```
import midi
pattern = midi.read_midifile("pachelbel_canon.mid")

#print out all events
print pattern
#print out all events at tick = 0
print pattern[0]
```

Interpretation of different event types can be found either on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29718532) or [Granroth-Wilding's website](http://jazzparser.granroth-wilding.co.uk/api/midi-module.html). My target values (tick, pitch and velocity) are presented as midi.NOteOn/OffEvent(tick=0, channel=0, data=[pitch, velocity]).

**Question 1:**
Since there's no tutorial nor documentation available, after some testing I figured `print pattern[0]` returns all events happened at tick == 0. Of course all data can be retrieved by running a for-loop over all events, I'm just wondering is there any function to retrieve data by providing other parameters e.g. channel, pitch etc.

**Question 2:**
Apparently there are lots of midi / music libraries available out there. Not saying python-midi is not decent, yet if you have anything better in mind please do share! Preferably comes with some proper documentation or support, which doesn't exist for python-midi. I'm new to this area and would love some recommendations.

Comment: Check out MIT's Music21 package -- http://web.mit.edu/music21/

Comment: @bgporter been playing with music21.. it's awesome! thanks pal.

Comment: I am voting to close this question: it is too broad (multiple questions) and it is requesting off-site resource.